# Linkedin iOS SDK: Wrong style on authorization screen when profile photo is empty

Tags: ios, xamarin, sdk, linkedin-api

We are using LinkedIn sdk to authorize an iOS mobile application access to the user's LinkedIn profile. App's made using Xamarin. Native LinkedIn sdk is binded so it should work the same way.

In case LinkedIn profile photo is empty, when the app is opened by the sdk to ask for authorization, styles are wrong.

The text indicating the app who's asking for permission is missing and the allow/cancel buttons seem to be moved to the left (see arrow in the image)

This seems to be happening inside LinkedIn app so I am guessing there is not too much to be done on my side but I was hoping someone already had this issue and have some hint. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: We are experiencing this too, I need to add that it can only be reproduced on some specific LinkedIn accounts. The bug is also reproduced even on official LinkedIn SDK samples.

Comment: @Olexander I only had a few devices to test with but I think it happens on the latest LinkedIn app version (they updated Nov 21th I think) a couple non updated devices worked just fine. Did you by any chance saw this same behavior?

Comment: No, I didn't have any chance to test it on the earlier version of LinkedIn app.

Comment: @Olexander there was a LinkedIn update on December 7th. Problem does not persist on this version.

Comment: We've figured out that it happens when LinkedIn profile image is empty, and it is also reproduced on the latest version 9.1.9 from 07 Dec 2016. So you need to delete profile photo to reproduce.

Comment: @JohannPérez Please post your observations as an answer and accept it as the appropriate solution. Otherwise, people, including me, will open the question trying to provide an answer.

Comment: @Demitrian this question is still open. Olexander managed to get the exact conditions when this happens and edited the question accordingly. The wrong behavior remains.