# Linkedin iOS SDK: Wrong style on authorization screen (can't tap blue button to confirm)

Tags: ios, sdk, authorization, linkedin-api, confirmation

[I can't tap on confirm button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX5i2.jpg)
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPREw.png)
Can't allow use my profile information for creating new account.
Similar problem here, but without solution. Please, help.
[Linkedin iOS SDK: Wrong style on authorization screen when profile photo is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874016/linkedin-ios-sdk-wrong-style-on-authorization-screen-when-profile-photo-is-empt)